# Por que arrays são covariantes e genéricos são invariantes?

Tags: java, array, genéricos, design-de-linguagem, variância

Arrays em Java são covariantes, isto é, é perfeitamente legal fazer algo como:

```
Number[] meuArray = new Integer[10];
```

Já tipos genéricos são invariantes. A linha abaixo não compila:

```
List<Number> minhaLista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Saída do compilador:

```
error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to List<Number>
        List<Number> minhaLista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                  ^
```

A questão é, por que decidiram implementar arrays covariantes?

---

**Pergunta original:** *[SOen - Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18666710/664577)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Arrays covariantes são considerados uma falha da linguagem. Idealmente eles deveriam ser invariantes também.

O principal motivo de eles terem sido concebidos como covariantes foi uma tentativa ruim de permitir a implementação de conjuntos genéricos de objetos, em especial para que métodos que trabalhassem com arrays de objetos pudessem trabalhar com arrays de qualquer tipo de objeto. Esse conceito na verdade é uma gambiarra, mas era uma gambiarra que possibilitava a criação de algum código que funcionasse de forma minimamente genérica.

Códigos que se aproveitavam do fato da covariância dos arrays são códigos que escrevem elementos no mesmo array de onde são lidos, tais como códigos que ordenam elementos de um array, ou o embaralham, ou os duplicam, etc. Um exemplo simples:

```
public static void embaralhar(Object[] array) {
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = (int) (Math.random() * (i + 1));
        Object temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Observe que uma vez que o tipo do parâmetro é `Object[]`, então ele pode ser usado para `String[]`, `Thread[]`, `Cachorro[]`, com base no raciocínio que **"se `String` é subclasse de `Object`, então `String[]` é subclasse de `Object[]`"**, ou seja, o código funciona por causa da covariância. O tipo da variável `temp` é `Object`, mas representa um objeto obtido de dentro do próprio array, e que portanto pode ser seguramente colocado nele de volta novamente. Note que no caso de você tentar usar a covariância para poluir um array com algo cujo tipo seja incompatível (e que portanto não possa ter vindo dele mesmo), tal como acrescentar um `Gato` em uma instância de `Cachorro[]` representado por uma variável do tipo `Object[]`, você vai tomar uma `ArrayStoreException`:

```
Cachorro[] array = new Cachorro[3];
Object[] mesmoArray = array;
mesmoArray[0] = new Gato(); // Estoura uma ArrayStoreException
```

Isso daí data da época do Java 1.0. Na verdade, é anterior até mesmo ao Java 1.0, já que surgiu ainda nos primeiros estágios do desenvolvimento do Java 1.0 quando o mesmo ainda era chamado de Oak. Naquela época, não se tinha os tipos genéricos que existem hoje (que surgiram com o Java 5). Também não se tinha o *Collections framework* desenvolvido como hoje em dia, e tudo que se referisse a coleções de objetos era tratado como array (conceito esse herdado do C e do C++). O máximo que se tinha na época eram as classes `Vector`, `Hashtable` e `Stack`, que sofrem de seríssimos problemas de modelagem e tinham como propósito mais servir de exemplo ou de quebra-galho do que para se fazer uma modelagem de dados decente.

O C++ tem templates, que poderiam servir de inspiração. Entretanto, os templates não eram bem vistos e não se queria imitá-los no Java. A razão disso é que o compilador C++ cria uma versão da classe ou método para cada combinação de templates encontrada, o que aumenta muito o tamanho do código executável produzido. Como a ideia do Java era poder rodar inclusive em dispositivos com pouca memória e baixo poder computacional, essa alternativa era proibitiva. E também os templates do C++ eram invariantes, e portanto um modelo parecido não serviria para se resolver muitos dos problemas enfrentados, tais como ordenar listas de elementos sem precisar saber o tipo. Assim sendo, o consenso da época era que Java não precisava disso.

Demorou-se um bom tempo (e uma boa dose de experiência prática e abuso de casts) para que se abandonasse tal consenso e se formasse alguma ideia que permitisse a introdução dos tipos genéricos sem o aumento do tamanho do código executável produzido e que tivesse boa flexibilidade em termos de covariância e contravariância. Disso surgiram o (odiado) *type-erasure* e o `super` e o `extends` que aparecem em alguns tipos genéricos. O `super` e o `extends` proveem contravariância e covariância respectivamente.

O *type-erasure* garante que na JVM os tipos genéricos desaparecem, fazendo eles serem apenas um truque introduzido pelo compilador. Basicamente, no Java com generics, o compilador acrescenta por debaixo dos panos os casts que seriam necessários no Java sem generics, o que é uma abordagem completamente diferente do que a adotada pelos templates do C++. Entretanto, essa solução baseada no *type-erasure* criou alguns problemas, pois tipos genéricos não podem ser protegidos de poluição de dados da mesma forma que arrays fazem (que têm o `ArrayStoreException` para isso). Além disso, a implementação dos arrays não pôde ser compatibilizada com os generics (e é por isso que misturar arrays com generics é difícil).

Um exemplo de poluição de dados (*heap pollution*):

```
List<Cachorro> cachorros = new ArrayList<>();

// O compilador dá uma warning unchecked.
List<Object> objetos = (List<Object>) cachorros;

// Poluição de dados aqui. Um gato é introduzido na lista de cachorros!
objetos.add(new Gato());

// Vai dar ClassCastException, mas não há nenhum cast neste código.
// Na verdade, o compilador introduziu um cast por debaixo dos panos.
Cachorro c = cachorros.get(0);
```

Se Java contasse com tipos genéricos implementados de forma adequada desde o começo, os arrays não necessitariam ser invariantes e o *type-erasure* não teria sido necessário. Entretanto, muito do conhecimento necessário para que os generics fossem de fato implementados e para demonstrar quais estratégias de implementação funcionariam ou não, só foi desenvolvido graças a experiência acumulada após uma grande quantidade de desenvolvedores Java sofrerem com esse problema e buscassem diversas soluções por si mesmos. Além disso, os generics são um monstrinho significativamente complicado e implementá-los desde o começo teria dificultado e atrasado muito o lançamento do Java como linguagem de programação, então apenas ter arrays covariantes acabou sendo a saída mais simples.

Comment: A propósito, muito esclarecedora a resposta :)

Comment: Olá Victor, excelente resposta (melhor do que as respostas na pergunta original que também são muito boas). Só o que tenho para contribuir é que esse tipo de variância usada nos genéricos do [tag:java] é classificada como *use-site* em oposição à variância *declaration-site* de linguagens como o [tag:c#]. Linguagens mais recentes como [tag:scala] e [tag:kotlin] permitem ambas (por exemplo: uma `List` em Scala é covariante em `T`). [Essa pergunta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231305/664577) entra em mais detalhes sobre essas diferenças.