# Qual a diferença entre "generics" (Java/C#) e "template" (C++)

Tags: java, c#, c++, genéricos, metaprogramação

Na pergunta [Quais as diferenças entre Tipos Genéricos em C# e em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10032/101) se mostrou a diferença entre o mecanismo de *generics* entre Java e C#. Sabemos que o C++ não possui *generics*, mas usa *templates* para isso.

Qual a diferença destes dois mecanismos dessas linguagens?

Comment: Resposta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148412/132

Comment: Ótima pergunta!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre o paradigma já respondido em [O que é programação genérica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101).

Para uma comparação mais detalhada só dos genéricos já pode ser vista na pergunta citada.

Genéricos são usados em diversas linguagens modernas tais como D, Rust, Swift, TypeScript, VB.NET, Delphi, Objective C, Eiffel, Ada, Hack, F# e outras diversas linguagens funcionais, etc. na verdade qualquer linguagem que deseja dar total segurança de tipos precisa ter esse mecanismo ou terá bem pouca flexibilidade.

Os gabaritos (*templates*) são usados para permitir o uso de genéricos, entre outras coisas. Esta é uma outra forma parecida com o [polimorfismo paramétrico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism), mas não igual.

## Porque existem

Em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica é fácil criar um algoritmo que sirva para diversas estruturas de dados (tipos diferentes). Quando usa-se a tipagem estática acaba sendo necessário replicar os algoritmos idênticos ou até outras estruturas que usam algum dado para compor. Isso costuma ser um absurdo.

Um truque comumente usado é criar uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) (ponteiro) e um tipo coringa. O problema disso é que essa indireção pode ser indesejada em alguns casos e não há mais a segurança de tipo tornando a linguagem virtualmente de tipagem dinâmica nesses casos.

A solução foi criar o tal do *generics* que nada mais é que uma parametrização do tipo de dado a ser usado em algum ponto de uma estrutura de dados (classe por exemplo) ou algoritmo (função). Assim o programador escreve uma vez e o compilador dá um jeito de usar essa definição com tipos diferentes de forma segura e quase sempre rápida.

Os gabaritos do C++ servem para isso e um pouco mais. Ele é mais poderoso e flexível permitindo o que costuma-se chamar metaprogramação. Então o objetivo principal de ambos é o mesmo, mas os *templates* vão além.

## Diferença TL;DR

Devemos entender *generics* como uma solução apenas para parametrização de tipos enquanto que os *templates* são uma solução, a grosso modo, para substituir as macros do C de uma forma mais confortável, poderosa e segura, permitindo praticamente tudo o que *generics* permite e muito mais. Na implementação do C++ há o objetivo de não gerar quaisquer custos adicionais na execução.

| Característica | C++ | C# | Java |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instanciação | Compilação | Execução | Não precisa |
| Segurança de tipos | Sim (quase) | Sim | Sim |
| Linguagem Turing Complete | Sim | Não | Não |
| Precisa do código fonte | Sim | Não | Não |
| Tempo de compilação típico | Longo | Curto | Curto |
| Relação de códigos:instâncias (tipos por valor) | 1:1 | 1:1 | Impossível |
| Relação de códigos:instâncias (por referência) | 1:1 | 1:N | 1:N |
| Parametrização de tipos | Sim | Sim | Sim |
| Parametrização de valores | Sim | Não | Não |
| Valores e tipos default | Múltiplas | Não | Não |
| Mensagens de erro compreensíveis | Nem Sempre | Boas | Boas |
| Facilidade para debugar | Não | Sim | Razoável |
| Capacidade de especialização | Sim | Não | Não |
| Especialização parcial/mixagem | Sim | Não | Não |
| Instanciação recursiva | Sim | Não | Não |
| Restrições de instanciação com subtipo | Não | Sim | Sim |
| Restrições na especialização | Sim | Não | Não |
| Facilidade para criar genéricos | Nem sempre | Sim | Sim |

## Detalhamento

A primeira grande diferença é que os *templates* são resolvidos totalmente em tempo de compilação. Nenhum vestígio deles são deixados para tempo de execução. Ajuda na performance da aplicação, mas aumenta o tamanho do código, já que cada instância especializada precisa ser criada no executável, e não dá maiores informações para depuração, afinal no código não existem todas essas instâncias das classes e/ou funções (note que instância aqui não é de objeto, mas sim do código genérico). É claro que o código-fonte é necessário por causa disto. Esse é um dos motivos da compilação ser mais lenta.

Mas é lento também porque permite fazer muito mais, tem muita situação complicada para analisar. O próprio sistema de gabaritos sozinho é considerado uma [linguagem de programação completa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101), permitindo criar códigos completos. Veja um exemplo clássico que é exagerado fazer, mas é possível:

```
template <int N>
struct factorial {
  enum { value = N * factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> {
  enum { value = 1 };
};

enum { result = factorial<5>::value }; // 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 == 120
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Template/Factorial.cpp).

Aí notamos duas características extras dos gabaritos. Permite recursão e aceita parametrização de valores, além de tipos. Poderia colocar um valor *default*, assim o valor poderia ser omitido na instanciação do valor específico. O mesmo vale para um tipo, assim se uma instância de uma função ou tipo genérico poderia ser criada mesmo sem especificar de que tipo ele deve ser - uma utilidade bem menor que o valor *default*.

Até existem técnicas manuais para aproveitar uma instância para vários tipos por referência (para fazer por valor vai adicionar uma indireção provavelmente indesejada), mas o normal é que cada tipo específico com potencial de ser usado vá gerar um código independente para cada combinação de parâmetros usados. Com um parâmetro já pode criar código demais, imagine com vários.

C# faz o mesmo para tipos por valor, mas para tipos por referência que já teriam uma indireção natural ele reaproveita. De qualquer forma, C# só cria a instância se ela for efetivamente usada em tempo de execução, o que gera um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) para o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). O Java só consegue fazer em tipos por referência (até a data que escrevi isso) e não precisa criar instâncias, sempre existirá apenas uma. O problema disso é que precisa fazer *casts* (mesmo que o compilador coloque automaticamente pelo programador) e costuma gerar ineficiências.

Note que o mecanismo de *template* é um gerador de código. Ele pega um código com parâmetros, troca por argumentos definidos na instanciação do recurso genérico. Pode fazer quase qualquer coisa. Essa flexibilidade cria alguma confusão. É fácil abusar. Por causa disso em várias situações as mensagens de erro do código gerado são bem confusas (anda melhorando muito).

Uma coisa legal nesses *templates* é que eles podem ser especializados. Então você pode ter um tipo ou valor específico com uma implementação própria diferente do que foi definido no genérico (como no exemplo acima). Pode fazer isso com partes, inclusive trazendo de outro código criando *mixins*. Isso é muito forte, tornando o recurso muito mais útil e podendo generalizar bem mais coisas porque consegue tratar até os casos que são exceções. E é possível restringir o que usar na especialização. Pode até dizer que só pode fazer se uma determinada operação está disponível. Há padrões de projeto conhecidos que ficam muito fáceis e performáticos se feitos com *templates*.

Versões mais novas do C++ e propostas futuras pretendem ampliar a capacidade de criar restrições ao que pode ser instanciado. Hoje isso é uma desvantagem. Tem caso que compila até o que não poderá ser executado, perdendo um pouco a segurança que deveria dar. Os genéricos puros possuem uma forma de restrição baseado em subtipos indicando quais tipos podem ser instanciados, garantindo segurança total.

*Templates* possuem um sistema de herança próprio que permite algumas técnicas bem sofisticadas e difíceis de fazer certo.

Comment: Devo dizer que li um artigo (acho que de 2017) que demonstrava que o _generics_ do Java era Turing Completo, vou atrás da fonte para poder atualizar a tabela caso a fonte se confirme

Comment: É, vi alguém falando disto mesmo.