# Como implementar uma interface para garantir um contrato específico?

Tags: c#, .net, modelagem, interface

Preciso fazer com que uma interface implemente uma lista de um determinado tipo:

```
public class ITrade<T>
{
    public int date { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

interface ITrades<T>
{
    List<ITrade<T>> Trades { get; set; }
}
```

Porém desejo que ITrade receba como parâmetro uma classe concreta:

```
    public class Trade
    {
       public int date { get; set; }
       public double price { get; set; }
       public double amount { get; set; }
       public int tid { get; set; }
       public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

A ideia é a seguinte: `Trade` está num arquivo de modelos e desejo que todo modelo tenha no mínimo as propriedades de `ITrade`. Ou seja, preciso forçar que os elementos da lista:

```
List<ITrade<T>> Trades { get; set; }
```

tenham no mínimo as propriedades de `ITrade` mais algumas propriedades a mais. Não posso colocar isso no `ITrade` porque quero separar uma interface geral que possa trabalhar com vários modelos e quero manter os modelos separados.

Comment: Você entendeu que a solução que postei é o que precisa? Você comentou na minha resposta e depois apagou. Não sei se foi porque percebeu que era exatamente o que queria ou se ainda não entendeu a solução. Seu comentário conforma exatamente minha resposta.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Tem vários problemas no código (sem falar que [C# não tem *templates*, tem *generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101)) e a pergunta não detalha muito a necessidade, mas eu acho que isto seria a solução:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var trade = new Trading();
        trade.Trades.Add(new Trade() {Tid = 1, Date = DateTime.Now, Price = 100M, Amount = 10M, Type = "um"});
        trade.Trades.Add(new Trade() { Tid = 2, Date = DateTime.Now, Price = 200M, Amount = 20M, Type = "dois"});
    }
}

public interface ITrade {
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
    decimal Amount { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}

interface ITrades {
    List<ITrade> Trades { get; set; }
}

public class Trade : ITrade {
    public int Tid { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Trading {
    public List<ITrade> Trades { get; set; } = new List<ITrade>();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PiaEeo). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7uA04s). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/InterfaceContract.cs).

Pelo que entendi a primeira classe deveria ser uma interface. E se ela não é genérica não tem porque usar o mecanismo de genericidade.

Implementei a segunda classe como achei que deveria só para testar. Na verdade tenho dúvida se isto é importante.

Mudei os tipos dos dados que estão errados. E melhorei os nomes para ficar no padrão do C#.

Fiz a classe implementada se conformar com a interface e atingir o objetivo descrito na pergunta.

Tem outros possível problemas mais de modelagem que não abordei.

Meu conselho seria começar fazer coisas mais básicas, aprender os recursos que está tentando usar antes de usá-los. O resultado será bem melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Então amigo, interface não é para forçar propriedades de classes e sim métodos,
para fazer com que outros modelos trade tenhas as mesmas propriedades, tem que criar uma classe abstrata e herdar ela nas outras, e uma interface com o método depois.

Conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
public abstract class TradeBase {
   DateTime Date { get; set; }
   decimal Price { get; set; }
   decimal Amount { get; set; }
   string Type { get; set; }
}

public interface ITrade {

}    


public class TradeA:TradeBase {
   decimal PropriedadeApenasDoTradeA{ get; set; }
}


E uma classe para receber as traders, ai voce pode passar qualquer um que herde da tradebase

public class Tradding
{
    public List<TradeBase> Traders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Propriedades na verdade são métodos. Não digo que sua resposta esteja errada, mas ela é *misleading*.