# Qual é a utilidade de classes genéricas no C#?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, genéricos, polimorfismo

Gostaria de validar meu entendimento sobre classes genéricas no C#, conforme descrito na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics).

Um exemplo:

```
// Declare the generic class.
public class GenericList<T>
{
    public void Add(T input) { }
}
class TestGenericList
{
    private class ExampleClass { }
    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare a list of type int.
        GenericList<int> list1 = new GenericList<int>();
        list1.Add(1);

        // Declare a list of type string.
        GenericList<string> list2 = new GenericList<string>();
        list2.Add("");

        // Declare a list of type ExampleClass.
        GenericList<ExampleClass> list3 = new GenericList<ExampleClass>();
        list3.Add(new ExampleClass());
    }
}
```

No eu entendimento, uma classe genérica poderia ser usada para implementar listas ou coleções de itens com tipos únicos mas que, a cada instância, podem assumir apenas o tipo informado na criação da instância.

Isso faria a classe genérica funcionar como uma espécie de *template*, onde (considerando o exemplo acima), todos os tipos `T` seriam "trocados" por `int` em `GenericList<int> list1 = new GenericList<int>();`; `T` seria "trocado" por `string` em `GenericList<string> list2 = new GenericList<string>();`; e assim por diante.

Estou correto no meu entendimento do mecanismo? Estou perdendo algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, ele serve para produzir quaisquer objetos genéricos, não necessariamente uma lista ou coleção. Qualquer objeto que tenha pelo menos um campo, e dentro da normalidade todos os tipos úteis têm isso, pode ser útil usar genericidade e o mesmo código gerar classes para cada tipo que for usado.

*Generics* é como o *template* que é usado em outras linguagens, porém é mais limitado no que pode instanciar, só aceitando tipos e de forma um pouco diferente.

Pode ver mais em:

- [O que é programação genérica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre "generics" (Java/C#) e "template" (C++)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101)

É possível fazer alguma restrição de que tipos a classe pode aceitar ali, já que em alguns casos pode ser que algumas operações não possam ser executadas de todos os tipos, por exemplo se faz algo aritmético, ainda que pra usar bem alguns casos numéricos ainda não tem como restringir de forma tão adequada (depende muito do caso), mas melhorará muito em C# 11.

Grosso modo de fato o `T` é mudado para os tipos da instanciação quando gera uma nova classe interna que o programador nem precisa saber que existe. Será uma para cada tipo (na verdade tem uma otimização e tipos por referência pode ter só uma classe gerada, então neste exemplo geraria duas classes internas). Então está correto, é quase uma troca de texto, mas feita de forma segura, semântica e com limitações.

Comment: Obrigado @maniero Então eu não estava de todo errado. Bem grosso modo, são como templates para tipagem. Vou ler o conteúdo sugerido.